# how to use navigation to setState() another screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, reload, drawer, invisible

i have problem with drawer in flutter i need to hide the sign in listtittle when iam logged in but it's not working by visible i think the reason is the sign in method is on another screen
here is the code of the drawer

```
if (_auth.currentUser == null)
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Visibility(
                      visible: _visible,
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text('Sign In'),
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {});

                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => SignIn()),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              else
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Visibility(
                      visible: _unvisible,
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text('My Cars'),
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => MyCars()),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: _unvisible,
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text('Sign Out'),
                        onTap: () {
                          signOut();
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

note: it's working when i press sign out the sign out list tittle disapear and the sign in is visible but when i'm signed in i need to refresh the page

this is the sign in button

```
new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            signin();

            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
            );
          },
          child: new Text('Sign In'),
        ),
```

note : this two pieces of code are from different classes

Comment: `_auth.currentUser` is not being saved when you open and close the app. You need to save the login state with sharedPreferences or something like that. Then check the flag to see whether to draw the sign in or not. https://medium.com/flutterdevs/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-251755f07127

Comment: its just returning an empty value when i try it , is there another way to solve this?

Comment: What is returning an empty value?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the situation, it appears that `_auth.currentUser` is not being saved properly. For a simple fix, you should implement something like [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) when the user logs in:

```
 //import
 import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';


 //somewhere in your login code put:
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 sharedPreferences.setString("logged_in", "true");
```

Personally I like to call shared_preferences in the initState:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getSharedPrefs();
    super.initState();
  }



 Future<Null> getSharedPrefs() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
```

---

**Then change the following:**

```
if (_auth.currentUser == null)
```

**To**

```
if (sharedPreferences.get("logged_in") == null)
```

---

**For logout:**

```
sharedPreferences.remove('logged_in');
```

Comment: the second part  says 'Undefined name 'sharedPreferences'' should i give it an initial value or something?.

Comment: `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;`  At the top of the class should work.

Comment: The method 'get' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: get("logged_in")  this error occur when i run the code

Comment: You need to initialize `sharedPreferences` like I do above in the `initState` or `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();`

Comment: i did this  `@override
  void initState() {
    getSharedPrefs();
    super.initState();
  }
  Future<Null> getSharedPrefs() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }`

Comment: i copied this part and placed it at the top of the class